# Multi VLAN Routing

Tags: routing, vlan

New to VLANs and need help. Based on the simple drawing included, how do I set up the 1510 switch to not only route between the 2 VLANs but also get non VLAN 10 traffic sent to the firewall GW?

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

- Create a interface vlan of vlan 10 on DGS-1510 and give it an IP in the range 10.16.122.xxx/24, Assign this IP as gateway of all the hosts in VLAN 10.
- Create a interface vlan of vlan 20 on DGS-1510 and give it an IP address in range 10.16.123.xxx/24, Assign this IP as gateway of all the hosts in VLAN 20.
- Give a default route on DGS-1510 with next-hop address 10.16.122.13.
- Give static route on firewall of 10.16.123.0/24 next-hop address 10.16.122.xxx(whatever IP you have put on DGS-1510 on interface VLAN 10).
- I take you have L2 domain of VLAN 10 and VLAN 20 configured already, You just have to put ports connected to hosts of VLANs in their respective VLANs

Hope this helps!

Comment: `Give static routes of 10.16.123.0/24` => you forgot to specify that this is on the firewall. Also, note that all traffic between vlan10 hosts and the outside will traverse vlan10 twice (since it goes to the 1510 first, and then from the 1510 to the firewall again over vlan10) so while this shouldn't be a problem per se, IMHO I would say RonTrunk's answer is more optimal as it creates a new vlan between the 1510 and the firewall.

Comment: **"you forgot to specify that this is on the firewall."** -- added, thanks!, **Also, note that all traffic between vlan10 hosts and the outside will traverse vlan10 twice** -- The solution was suggested to avoid making new changes to setup and just add a few things **with minimal configuration, without creating new VLANs**, Ron's answer has little typos(although not a problem if message is clear), also couldn't understand why create a VLAN with /24 with the problem can be solved with /30

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new VLAN for the link between the Firewall and the 1510.  For example, make it 10.16.125.0/24.  The FW can be 10.16.125.2.
- Configure a VLAN interface for each VLAN on the 1510 and give it an IP address in the VLAN.  For example,
  interface VLAN 10 might be 10.16.124.1.  The new VLAN can be 10.16.125.1
- Create a static route on the 1510 for 0.0.0.0/0 with the next hop 10.16.125.2.
- Create a static route on your firewall on the inside (trusted) interface for 10.16.0.0/16 with the next hop 10.16.125.1
- All the ports connected to the vlan 10 switches will be configured in VLAN 10; The port to the other switch will be on vlan 20
- Devices on each VLAN will use the vlan interface you have configured
  as their default gateway

Comment: `Create a static route on the 1510 for 0.0.0.0/0 with the next hop 10.16.122.13.1` => that next hop should be the new firewall address 10.16.125.2, shouldn't it?

Comment: @hertitu Yes -- typed too fast.  I fixed it.